# Excel - list names from one Sheet based on IDs from another one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm totally basic Excel user.
I received some data in CSV format that I need to connect.
This is what I have (simplified)

Sheet 1:
[image]
List of pages with IDs and other data.

Sheet 2:
[image]
Mapping page to categories one-to-many

Sheet 3:
[image]
List of category names and category IDs

I need a formula that for each row in categories column (sheet1 col C) will add comma-separated names of categories for that page (page ID).

I guess this is very easy for someone with at least medium experience in Excel formulas.
Please help.

Comment: `VLOOKUP`, maybe? Can you post what you tried and what problem you encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample, the formula would be:

```
=TEXTJOIN( ",", 1, XLOOKUP( FILTER( Sheet2!$B$2:$B$7, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7=Sheet1!A2 ), Sheet3!$A$2:$A$4, Sheet3!$B$2:$B$4,, 0 ) )
```

[image]

Comment: mark fitzpatrick, many many thanks. It works perfectly